# Getting HTTP 501 Not Implemented when there is definitely an implementation?

Tags: javascript, c++, http, restbed

I'm attempting to make a simple http service, I've got GET and POST working so far.  For some reason though every time I try to send a PUT, my restbed server returns 501, even though I have the method handler set for PUT.

The PUT, POST, and GET methods are set the exact same way, via `resource->set_method_handler("METHOD", METHOD_method_handler);`

The handler / setup

```cpp
void put_method_handler(const std::shared_ptr<restbed::Session>& session) {
  const auto request = session->get_request();

  std::cout << "yes\n";
}

int main() {
  auto resource = std::make_shared<restbed::Resource>();
  resource->set_path("/resource");
  resource->set_method_handler("PUT", put_method_handler);

  // bla bla service.publish() etc
}
```

Currently using a simple javascript FETCH via the chrome console to just see if it's recieving anything.

```js
fetch("http://localhost:1234/resource", {method: 'PUT', body: {}})
```

My server should be printing the `cout` statement, but instead it is silent and the `fetch` returns 501.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem ended up being that our restbed implementation had broken. Don't know the cause of that, but removing it and redownloading worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked [how restbed developers test `put` method](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/blob/master/test/feature/source/http_method_handlers/http_put.cpp).. Below is the code snippet:

```
void put_handler( const shared_ptr< Session > session )
{
    session->close( 200, "Hello, World!", { { "Content-Length", "13" }, { "Connection", "close" } } );
}

SCENARIO( "publishing single path resources", "[resource]" )
{
    auto resource = make_shared< Resource >( );
    resource->set_path( "/resources/1" );
    resource->set_method_handler( "PUT", put_handler );
    ...
}
```

My guess is that you're not returning success code in your put handler so that server thinks that not explicit code returned means the method is not implemented.

Comment: restbed seemingly doesn't care if you don't return a response code. When I was getting the GET method going I never responded anything and it was fine.  The real problem is that none of the code in `put_method_handler` is being run.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow though.  I'll come back here and mark it if it works, but I very much doubt it will.

Comment: Yes, please check and get back with the results. As per HTTP specification, GET request must not return 501 error (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/501). Probably this is why GET is handled in some special way in restbed..

Comment: Hey sorry I'm really late for this...
Problem ended up being that our restbed implementation had broken.  Don't know the cause of that, but removing it and redownloading worked.